# Help desk software - specific feature needed

Tags: helpdesk

I am having a hard time finding help desk software that allows for drop down hyperlink selection during ticket creation.

The situation is that we do external support for client systems and connect via remotely anywhere or logmein. Right now we use a poorly modified php based system that has a customer drop down menu and then a site drop down list that is then parsed by a bit of java script which opens a url.

What I am looking for is the ability to store customer site URL information in the database and during the creation of a ticket be able to select the customer name and then select the site there by placing the corresponding site URL in the ticket. The support tech will then be able to click on this link to access the customer's site.

Has anyone used or seen help desk software with this feature?

Comment: Have you looked at MSP software? They can handle many of the things you probably do including remote access.  I've only used Kaseya and would have a hard time recommending it but there are others out there.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I had never heard of the term Managed Service Provider software before.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do something like that with [RT](http://bestpractical.com/rt/), in the custom field part. My users can select an affected system during ticket creation - this is then displayed in form of a link on the ticket page - I use it to open an info page for the system, which currently includes some basic info like when it was last seen, network activity from mrtg in most cases, disk space etc., but this could easily be a link with a redirector script or something.

Comment: I have messed with the custom fields in RT but I do not see how to have a custom field appear during ticket creation.

Answer (score 0):

This is what we use, might have what you are looking for: [ServiceDesk](http://www.manageengine.com/products/service-desk/trouble-ticket-software.html)

During ticket creation, we select a user, in which is tied to an asset, etc... might be worth looking into.